# Table in footnotes

Tags: tables, footnotes

I would like to include tables in footnotes

```
\footnotetext{SOME TEXT

TABLE

SOME TEXT}
```

I can use the `tabular` environment, but the `begin{table}` with the caption and the label doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot have floats inside floats. I do not think this is a good idea in any case, will just annoy the reader. You can use the `caption` package to access a non-floating cation called `\captionof`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Often times when LaTeX won't let you do something, there is a good reason for it. *This is one of those times.* What overall problem are you trying to solve? What idea are you trying to get across to your reader? There *must* be a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved by defining a `mytable` environment, as shown below.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mytable}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

**Updated:** New Code to include List of Table and label reference.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false,justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} 
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mytable}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize} % for proper caption fontsize
\begin{document}
\listoftables


\section{section A}

Creating a footnote with table is easy in Table \ref{tab1} below.\footnote{
\begin{mytable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
head1 & head2\\ \hline
A & B\\ \hline
C & D\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}\label{tab1}
\end{mytable}
}

\end{document}
```

Old Code without `List of Tables`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mytable}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Creating a footnote with table is east.\footnote{
\begin{mytable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
head1 & head2\\ \hline
A & B\\ \hline
C & D\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%\caption{caption}
\end{mytable}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you need to wrap the `tabular` environment in a custom environment in order to typeset it in a footnote?

Comment: Oh, if caption is desired and shows up in LOT then the new environment is required. So if NO caption, then `tabular` is sufficient.

Comment: I had posted the comment because your MWE doesn't actually feature a caption to go with the tabular material.

Comment: On your remark, I added the caption and label to show it will work, answering OP's concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve your objective by loading the `caption` package and using its `\captionof` macro to create a non-floating table-like environment in a footnote. Since the font size in footnotes is, well, given by `\footnotesize`, it's necessary to issue the command `\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}` to assure that the font size in use in the caption matches that of the footnote material.

The captions generated by `\captionof{table}{...}` can be assigned `\label`s, which can be cross-referenced anywhere in the body of the document. The footnote that contains a table can, of course, also be cross-referenced directly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,lipsum} % lipsum for filler text
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\setlength\textheight{7cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, 
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum 
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate 
a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\footnote{%
\label{fn:first}
\lipsum[2]
\medskip
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
c & d \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize} % use \footnotesize for caption 
\captionof{table}{A table in a footnote}\label{tab:fn}
}

Here's a cross-reference to \autoref{tab:fn}, and here's a cross-reference to \autoref{fn:first}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [H] parameter from the float package can work too but the table and the caption appear in normal size:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{float}
    \begin{document}
    Some text\footnote{Text text text


    \begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    A&B\\ 
    C&D\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Footnote table}
    \label{footnote}
    \end{table}

    }

    \end{document}
```